# What happens when @EnableWebSecurity is used more that once?

Tags: spring-security

I have an application with two configuration classes:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigOne extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  ...
}

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigTwo extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  ...
}
```

And they are both instantiated in spring.

This doesn't seem to cause any obvious problems, but I'm afraid that I'm abusing the framework.  I have looked into what the annotation is pulling in, but it is not entirely clear to me what is happening in the security context by instantiating the objects twice.  Does anyone know what Frankenstein monster I have wrought?  Will this lead to any security gaps or bugs?